# Why can't make http request in android?

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I want to make http request in android.

```
try {
    URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
    c.connect();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Error is " + e.getMessage());
}
```

This is my code and when I check logs here is "Error is null".
Note! I use permissions: android.permission INTERNET and android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
I think that I don't have mistake but my app cann't make request.

Does anybody know what might be problem?

Comment: I have already seen every post but problem is still unresolved.
I wrote desktop app in Netbeans and my code worked fine here!!

Comment: Did you try adding a breakpoint to see what the exception is?  Did you check the documentation?

Comment: If I comment line "c.connect();" I will not have error but it's not good way.
I don't understand what is problem.

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to use a debugger.  Are you testing your app on an actual phone or using an emulator?

Comment: I use my own mobile. API19 android version: 4.4.2(kitkat)

Comment: You should post the full code where you are making the call.  If you call from the main thread your app will hang.

Comment: I wrote this code in MainActivity.java file. public void onCreate()  {here}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onClick(View v) {

        new MyAsyncTask().execute("lol");
    }
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {


        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            try {
                URL u = new URL("http://www.sahdeepsingh.com");
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
                c.connect();

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("TAG", "Error is " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And you will see connected in android moniter.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work.

Comment: @Mathew Are you using Asynchronous method?

Comment: I'm new in android so I don't have any answer.
Can you explain me how to use this method please?

Comment: Asynctasks are used to process certain tasks in background.Use this link https://www.studytutorial.in/android-httpurlconnection-post-and-get-request-tutorial for more reference and how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want me to update code i can do it.

Comment: Why not. Show me please.

Comment: okay give me sometime

Comment: Do you want whole my project?

Comment: This code will definitly work.I have used your code and there is a button in xml only. when you run it you will see conneted in log in android emulator.

Comment: Did you make a request?

Comment: see the try block bro.

Comment: When I clicked on the button it didn't call MyAsyncTask!!! Can you send me your project via Email?I think My project is not valid.

Comment: https://github.com/SahdeepSingh/Test here

Comment: Thank you very much. It works!!! I spent about 4 days fixing this problem.

Comment: Anytime.Glad worked for you. :)